# Cannot record audio with Cordova Media plugin on Windows (Phone) 8.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create an app that allows the user to record audio. I'm using the [`cordova-plugin-media`](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media) for this.

Using the sample from the documentation I can record sound on iOS (specifying a *.wav file), Android (*.amr), Windows Phone 8 (*.aac), but Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't work. I've tried it with *.mp3, *.wma, and *.m4a, but in every case I get this error:

> No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content.

Here's part of the code:

```
var that = this;

try {
    this._media = new Media('recording.mp3', function () {
        that._log('Audio success');
    }, function (e) {
        that._log('Error: ' + e.code + ': ' + e.message);
    });

    // Bind buttons
    document.querySelector('#recordStart').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Record
        that._log('Recording...');
        that._media.startRecord();
    });

    document.querySelector('#recordStop').addEventListener('click', function () {
        that._log('Recording stopped');
        that._media.stopRecord();
    });
}
catch (e) {
    this._log('An error occurred!');
    this._log(e.message);
}
```